# How to get Opportunity Relations in Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

In Opportunity screen, the definition of the data view for Relations is simply :

```
public CRRelationsList<CROpportunity.noteID> Relations;
```

When a Sales Order is raised from the Opportunity. I'd like to display the Relations defined from the source Opporunity in another tab. And I'm just struggling how to write the the data view and pass the Opportunity noteid.

```
public CRRelationsList<???>Relations;
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic type in dataviews often resolve to the current record.

In `CRRelationsList` class the generic type is named `TNoteField`:

```
public class CRRelationsList<TNoteField> : PXSelect<CRRelation>
    where TNoteField : IBqlField
```

ssuming the dataview is declared as `CRRelationsList<CROpportunity.noteID>`.

The generic type value will be resolved like this `Caches[typeof(CROpportunity)].Current.NoteID`.

```
protected virtual void CRRelation_RefNoteID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache sender, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    // Get a cache object of type CROpportunity
    var refCache = sender.Graph.Caches[BqlCommand.GetItemType(typeof(TNoteField))];

    // Get the NoteID field value of the current CROpportunity object
    e.NewValue = refCache.GetValue(refCache.Current, typeof(TNoteField).Name);
}
```

So to set `DAC.Field` of `CRelationsList<DAC.field>` you would do:

```
// In a graph extension (PXGraphExtension)
Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)].Current.Fied = ???;

// Or in graph (PXGraph)
Caches[typeof(DAC)].Current.Fied = ???;
```

If current DAC object is null you need to insert a record in a dataview or directly in the cache object.

I'm not sure re-using `CRRelationsList` list is the best approach if you want to simply display records because it does much more than that. It should be possible to extract the select request out of it and directly substitute the `TNoteField` value:

```
private static PXSelectDelegate GetHandler()
{
    return () =>
    {
        var command = new Select2<CRRelation,
            LeftJoin<BAccount, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<CRRelation.entityID>>,
            LeftJoin<Contact,
                        On<Contact.contactID, Equal<Switch<Case<Where<BAccount.type, Equal<BAccountType.employeeType>>, BAccount.defContactID>, CRRelation.contactID>>>,
            LeftJoin<Users, On<Users.pKID, Equal<Contact.userID>>>>>,
            Where<CRRelation.refNoteID, Equal<Current<TNoteField>>>>();

        var startRow = PXView.StartRow;
        int totalRows = 0;
        var list = new PXView(PXView.CurrentGraph, false, command).
            Select(null, null, PXView.Searches, PXView.SortColumns, PXView.Descendings, PXView.Filters,
                    ref startRow, PXView.MaximumRows, ref totalRows);
        PXView.StartRow = 0;
        foreach (PXResult<CRRelation, BAccount, Contact, Users> row in list)
        {
            var relation = (CRRelation)row[typeof(CRRelation)];
            var account = (BAccount)row[typeof(BAccount)];
            relation.Name = account.AcctName;
            relation.EntityCD = account.AcctCD;
            var contact = (Contact)row[typeof(Contact)];
            if (contact.ContactID == null && relation.ContactID != null &&
                account.Type != BAccountType.EmployeeType)
            {
                var directContact = (Contact)PXSelect<Contact>.
                                                    Search<Contact.contactID>(PXView.CurrentGraph, relation.ContactID);
                if (directContact != null) contact = directContact;
            }
            relation.Email = contact.EMail;
            var user = (Users)row[typeof(Users)];
            if (account.Type != BAccountType.EmployeeType)
                relation.ContactName = contact.DisplayName;
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(relation.Name))
                    relation.Name = user.FullName;
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(relation.Email))
                    relation.Email = user.Email;
            }
        }
        return list;
    };
}
```